# How to find minimum versions of python interpreter and libs using CMake

Tags: python, cmake, python-extensions

I am building a C extension using pybind11 with CMake. I used to do this with:

```
find_package(Python3 3.7 REQUIRED)
find_package(PythonLibs 3.7 REQUIRED)
```

without any issues. Now I need python 3.8 and changed it to:

```
find_package(PythonInterp 3.8 REQUIRED)
find_package(PythonLibs 3.8 REQUIRED)
```

However, despite libpython3.8.so being in the same folder as libpython3.7m.so CMake does not find it. It returns:

```
Could NOT find PythonLibs: Found unsuitable version "3.7.5", but required
is at least "3.8" (found /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.7m.so)
```

When researching this I noticed that PytonInterp and PythonLibs are deprecated since CMake 3.12 and FindPython is preferred. So I tried:

```
find_package(Python3)
```

This finds my python 3.8 interpreter, but not my python 3.8 libraries. Hence, I still cannot use the package, as

```
mypy.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
```

is based on python 3.7 libraries. How can I ensure it also finds my 3.8 libraries? As said, they are in the same folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation for the [FindPython](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.12/module/FindPython3.html) module states:

> If no `COMPONENTS` are specified, `Interpreter` is assumed.

So, yes, since you haven't specified any `COMPONENTS`, only the interpreter is found.

If you want CMake to find the Python *include directories and libraries*, you should specify `Development`:

```
find_package(Python3 COMPONENTS Interpreter Development)
```